# Are CollectionViewSources nestable?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, collections

tldr: CollectionViewSource.Filter is overwritten by another control. How can I have two tiers of filtering so that the control only sees a prefiltered collection?

I have a third-party gridcontrol that I bind to a collection in my viewmodel via an ICollectionView.

```
private CollectionViewSource _filteredCollection;

public ItemListViewModel (List<ItemViewModel> items)
{
    _items = items;
    _filteredCollection = new CollectionViewSource {Source = _items};
}

public ICollectionView AllInstructions
{
    get { return _filteredCollection.View; }
}
```

This works fine and allows the gridcontrol to do its own filtering, grouping and sorting. 
Now I want to apply my own filter before the grid's one (i.e. a button to only show today's Items)

```
public ItemListViewModel (List<ItemViewModel> items)
{
    ...
    _filteredCollection.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterByDate);
}

private void FilterByDate(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item as ItemViewModel;

    if (item == null)
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = item.CreatedDate >= _selectedDate;
    }
}
```

My new filter works as expected. 
The problem is, the gridcontrol doesn't play nicely with it and just overwrites any filters with its own.

The idea I had was to perform my filtering on the _filteredCollection CVS and then create another CollectionViewSource or CollectionView around it that I pass to the gridcontrol.

If I wrap _filteredCollection in an ICollectionView, the two tiers of filtering work perfectly but I cannot sort or group because the default constructor for ICollectionView has CanSort and CanGroup set to false.

What I can't figure out is how to feed _filteredCollection into the second CollectionViewSource's constructor. Is it possible or am I approaching this problem from the wrong angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own collection view with predefined filter by deriving from [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx), like in the following code:

```
class FilteredListCollectionView : ListCollectionView
{
    // internal filter
    private Predicate<object> preFilter;

    // public filter
    private Predicate<object> filter;

    public FilteredListCollectionView(IList list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    private Predicate<object> GetCombinedFilter()
    {
        if (this.preFilter != null)
            return this.filter != null ? x => this.preFilter(x) && this.filter(x) : this.preFilter;
        else
            return this.filter;
    }

    public Predicate<object> PreFilter
    {
        get { return this.preFilter; }
        set
        {
            this.preFilter = value;
            base.Filter = this.GetCombinedFilter();
        }
    }

    public override Predicate<object> Filter
    {
        get { return base.Filter; }
        set
        {
            this.filter = value;
            base.Filter = this.GetCombinedFilter();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
private FilteredListCollectionView _filteredCollection;

public ItemListViewModel(List<ItemViewModel> items)
{
    _items = items;
    _filteredCollection = new FilteredListCollectionView(_items);
    _filteredCollection.PreFilter = FilterByDate;
}

public ICollectionView AllInstructions
{
    get { return _filteredCollection; }
}

private bool FilterByDate(object obj)
{
    var item = obj as ItemViewModel;

    if (item == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return item.CreatedDate >= _selectedDate;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this with any control, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, you want to apply several filters to your list, don't you ?

How about suscribing Filter to a main FilterHandler that manages your several predicates. To make it more flexible, you could add these predicates to a list or a stack that your main FilterHandler will unstack. Thanks to the refreshing process of CollectionViewSources, I believe any new filter will be taken into account on the next Refresh().